# SQL Function Replace Non-numeric Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-function

What I'm trying to do is create an SQL function where it checks if a number has any non-numeric characters and if it does remove them. But if the number has a `+1234`, leave it. So some number have `1234` and some have have `+1234`. I dont want to add `+` to all the numbers.

Here is my SQL function below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION[dbo].[fn_NonNumericCharacters] ( @strText varchar(1000) )
RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
AS
BEGIN
WHILE PATINDEX('%[^+0-9]%', @strText) > 0
BEGIN
    SET @strText = STUFF(@strText, PATINDEX('%[^+0-9]%', @strText), 1,    '')
END
RETURN @strText
END
```

What I'm trying to do with this function is make it look for these characters `()-,.SPACE .`

What do you think?

Comment: Does it do the job you want it to do? If so, [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) might be a better site to ask on.

Comment: Do you only want to replace these characters: `()-,.SPACE`?  Performance-wise, a nested replace should be faster.

Comment: Im not sure if it will work yet, i was just wondering id this line     'SET @strText = STUFF(@strText, PATINDEX('%[^+0-9]%', @strText), 1,    '')' , while make all number +1234 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the first char if its a `+`, replace `+`, re-append, return:

```
CREATE FUNCTION[dbo].[fn_NonNumericCharacters] ( @strText varchar(1000) )
RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @prefix VARCHAR(1) = CASE WHEN @strText LIKE '+%' THEN '+' ELSE '' END

  WHILE PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strText) > 0
      SET @strText = STUFF(@strText, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strText), 1,    '')

  RETURN @prefix + @strText
END
```

Comment: CASE WHEN LEFT(@strText,1) = '+' may be a bit faster.

Comment: Thanks so, that looks for '+',  then replaces it?, but i dont want to replace it.

Comment: Yes, but then it restores the leading `+` if the input began with `+` so `'+123+4Z56'  => '+123456'`